# How to deploy Express 4 application with mysql database setup on openshift?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am finding it difficult to deploy the Express4 app on Openshift.
The project is working fine on localhost but not being able to push on server

```
remote: Git Post-Receive Result: failure
remote: Activation status: failure
remote: Activation failed for the following gears:
remote: 55d6d1367628e11bda000128 (Error activating gear: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control start' for /var/lib/openshift/nodejs
remote: #<IO:0x000000017462a0>
remote: #<IO:0x00000001746228>
remote: )
remote: Deployment completed with status: failure
remote: postreceive failed
```

The app deployment fails on server.js ....

The express@3 version  works fine on server.js(default they provide).
Any help for deploying express@4 version on openshift ???